# Adding entry to a deque c++

Tags: c++, populate, deque

I have a struct

```
typedef struct myStruct {
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> something;
   std::complex<double> const &x;
   std::complex<double> const &y;
   unsigned int const z;
   unsigned int const w;
   unsigned int const m;
} myStruct;
```

And I created a deque based on this type of struct like:

```
std::deque<myStruct> deq;
```

Now, I would like to populate a new function adding a new entry to this deque:

```
void newFunction(...){
deq.insert(...);
}
```

How can I populate this function adding a new entry to my deque, that is a myStruct type? My problem is that I have some references in the struct type and can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Define a constructor for `myStruct ` and then use `deq.emplace_back`.

Comment: How? When I'm declaring a new constructor in newFunction like:  myStruct *newStruct = new myStruct() and then deq.emplace_back(); I get errors for not declaring parameters of the struct

Comment: You don't need all the old `typedef struct myStruct {...} myStruct;` syntax. You can just do `struct myStruct {...};`.

Comment: yeah, but I can't modify the struct. I only need to populate the newFunction with a new entry to this queue. How?

Comment: how do you create a `myStruct` if you dont put it in a deque?

Comment: I created the struct and then I created a deque with that struct type, and that inizialized the deque

Comment: Ugh, you're right. TIme for more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Your type `myStruct` has no constructor — not one that you've declared (because you haven't) and not one that the compiler's synthesised for you (because it has no way of knowing how to).

It is of course possible to create objects of that type using aggregate initialisation, which is the only avenue you've left for yourself:

```
std::complex<double> x, y;
myStruct obj = {{}, x, y, 1, 2, 3};
```

You should now be able to copy-construct a deque element from it:

```
deq.push_back(obj);
```

But you're not going to be able to use `emplace_back` to construct in-place until the type has a constructor.

You *can* use `emplace_back` to invoke the synthesised move-constructor:

```
deq.emplace_back(std::move(obj));
```

but you still want a proper constructor for your type.

Also, since `myStruct` contains `const` members, it is not copy-assignable. For this, and for a few other reasons, the type is not designed properly for use in a standard container.

And I'm nervous about storing "raw" references inside an object then putting that object in a container. What's ensuring the validity of those references?

Finally, stop with the unnecessary `typedef` idiom. This is something we did in C back in the 1820s so that we could call the type `myStruct` instead of `struct myStruct` everywhere; in C++, `myStruct` is a class and you can just name it directly without any of that trickery. Sometimes people stick with the `typedef` trick when their class also needs to be included into C source code, i.e. for compatibility, but with `std::vector` and `std::complex` members you're assuredly not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

First, a constructor in your structure which initializes all elements.

```
   myStruct(std::vector<std::vector<int>> v, 
    std::complex<double> const &x,
    std::complex<double> const &y,
    unsigned int const z,
    unsigned int const w,
    unsigned int const m): something(v), x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w), m(m) {}
```

Next, in your `newFunction`, use `emplace_back` to insert an element at the end of the deque.

```
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v; //Initialize this vector if required.
   std::complex<double> const x = {1.0, 2.0}; //Example
   std::complex<double> const y = {1.0, 2.0};
   unsigned int const z = 10;
   unsigned int const w = 20;
   unsigned int const m = 30;
   deq.emplace_back(v, x, y, z, w, m);
```

Comment: Why create a temporary? Just give `emplace_back` the ctor args directly; that's what it's for.

Comment: Not required. Just keeping it simple. Don't know the experience level of OP.

Comment: Adding in a temporary makes it _less_ simple, and the experience level of OP is affected by what we teach them!

Comment: Okay, will go with you on this. Updated.